# Parallelize a method from inside a CUDA device function / kernel

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, cuda, dynamic-parallelism

I've got an already parallelized CUDA kernel that does some tasks which require frequent interpolation.

So there's a kernel

```
__global__ void complexStuff(...)
```

which calls one or more times this interpolation device function:

```
__device__ void interpolate(...)
```

The interpolation algorithm does an WENO interpolation successively over three dimensions. This is a highly parallelizable task which I urgently would like to parallelize!

It is clear that the kernel `complexStuff()` can easily be parallelized by calling it from host code using the `<<<...>>>` syntax. It is also important that `complexStuff()` is already parallelized.

But it's not clear to me how to parallelize something / create new threads from inside a CUDA device function ... is this even possible? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider Dynamic Parallelism (some resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10854325/2386951), [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0338-GTC2012-CUDA-Programming-Model.pdf), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19528633/2386951)) in order to call a CUDA kernel from inside another CUDA kernel. It requires your device compute capability to be 3.5 or higher. It comes with a number of restrictions and limitations that may degrade the performance (mentioned in 3rd link).
My suggestion is to first consider calling your CUDA kernel with `complexStuff(...)` amount of work multiplied by `interpolate(...)` amount work. In other words, statically guess what is the maximum parallel fine-grained *Jobs* you need to do. Then configure your kernel to perform those fine-grained *jobs* with block threads. Note that it's just a speculation without knowing your program code.